# SQLite concat "||" query not working in C# data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I was trying to develop a query,
where I have two tables,
in second table I have two foreign keys from the first table in separate columns,
and I am replacing these foreign keys with their actual row value,
and then trying to concatenate some columns as a single result.

```
SELECT Conversions.ID,
       [1 ] || BASE.FULLNAME || [ = ] || Conversions.RATE || [ ] || SEC.FULLNAME AS CONVERSION,
       Conversions.[BASE UNIT] AS BASE,
       Conversions.[SECONDARY UNIT] AS SECONDARY
  FROM Conversions
       INNER JOIN
       Units AS BASE ON (Conversions.[BASE UNIT] = BASE.ID) 
       INNER JOIN
       Units AS SEC ON (Conversions.[SECONDARY UNIT] = SEC.ID);
```

This is my query and I also verified the output of the query in SQLiteStudio, and it is as expected.

[SQLite studio output for above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcRos.png)

But when I try to use this query in my C# data grid view, view remains blank.

I am new to C# WinForms, Please guide me through debugging and tools if necessary.

Comment: You have columns with names like `1 ` and ` = ` and a space?

Comment: No it is output row where I need to print "1 value_from_column_1 = rate_from_column_2 value_from_column_1". To concatenate the result I used 1 empty space and = string. Again I repeat the fact that the above query works fine in SQLiteStudio.

Comment: Strings in SQL use single quotes. Square brackets are one of several non-standard forms of quoting table and column names supported by sqlite (Standard SQL, and what you really should be using instead, uses double quotes for identifiers that need quoting)

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html for details.

Comment: @Shawn thank you for answering the question, please post it as a answer. I will accept it.